# How to rename the layer name in PCB Editor?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, cadence, allegro

How can I can edit or change the following layer name?
[image]

I am a self learner of PCB editor. I was trying to design the copy of a file I already have (A reference board file). The below picture is the top layer name of the PCB reference board file. The default layer name for the board I have been working on is simply "TOP". How can I change the class name from "TOP" to "L01_TOP". I know the layer name does not matter much, but I would like to know how to edit it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I delete it and add my own with right-click, "Add Manual". Make sure to write down what is in it before deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Artwork Control Form, Double-click the layer named "TOP" then it will become editable. Type the desired layer name, then hit Tab (or Enter, or click outside the name field) to commit the name change.